# "IS NOT NULL" not producing the required results in mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, mariadb, having

I am trying to build a report based of my table. Here is my table:

[image]

Following is the SQL query to get desired results.

```
SELECT
  `user`,
  SUM(
    CASE
      WHEN `event_time` >= '2021-04-01 00:00:00'
      AND `event_time` <= '2021-04-16 23:59:59'
      AND `sub_status` = 'TB'
      THEN pause_sec
    END
  ) AS 'Training Break',
  SUM(
    CASE
      WHEN `event_time` >= '2021-04-01 00:00:00'
      AND `event_time` <= '2021-04-16 23:59:59'
      AND `sub_status` = 'SB1'
      THEN pause_sec
    END
  ) AS 'Short Break 1',
  SUM(
    CASE
      WHEN `event_time` >= '2021-04-01 00:00:00'
      AND `event_time` <= '2021-04-16 23:59:59'
      AND `sub_status` = 'SB2'
      THEN pause_sec
    END
  ) AS 'Short Break 2',
  SUM(
    CASE
      WHEN `event_time` >= '2021-04-01 00:00:00'
      AND `event_time` <= '2021-04-16 23:59:59'
      AND `sub_status` = 'LB'
      THEN pause_sec
    END
  ) AS 'Long Break'
FROM
  `vicidial_agent_log`
GROUP BY `user`
```

[image]

I am looking to exclude entries which have all null values and following is my syntax but it is not working and produces the same results.

```
FROM
  `vicidial_agent_log`
WHERE 'Training Break' IS NOT NULL
  AND 'Short Break 1' IS NOT NULL
  AND 'Short Break 2' IS NOT NULL
  AND 'Long Break' IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY `user`
```

Kindly help here or share a post that can help. I have been trying to find but

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use single quotes for column names/aliases, because for example `'Training Break'` in an expression like `'Training Break' IS NOT NULL` is interpreted as a string literal which of course is not null.

In MySql you can use backticks to surround column names.

Also, the columns `Training Break`, `Short Break 1`, `Short Break 2` and `Long Break` are the result of aggregate functions so they can't be used in a `WHERE` clause. Instead use a `HAVING` clause.

Finally, since you want the rows where at least 1 of these columns is not null you should use the operator `OR` instead of `AND`:

```
FROM
  `vicidial_agent_log`
GROUP BY `user`
HAVING `Training Break` IS NOT NULL
    OR `Short Break 1` IS NOT NULL
    OR `Short Break 2` IS NOT NULL
    OR `Long Break` IS NOT NULL
```

Or:

```
FROM
  `vicidial_agent_log`
GROUP BY `user`
HAVING COALESCE(`Training Break`, `Short Break 1`, `Short Break 2`, `Long Break`) IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

First, move the common part of the `SUM()` expressions to the `WHERE` clause.

Second, fix the date logic so you are not missing a second.

I also strongly, strongly recommend using column names that do not need to be escaped.  So:

```
SELECT user,
      SUM(CASE WHEN sub_status` = 'TB' THEN pause_sec END) AS Training_Break,
      SUM(CASE WHEN sub_status = 'SB1' THEN pause_sec END) AS Short_Break_1,
      SUM(CASE WHEN sub_status = 'SB2' THEN pause_sec END) AS Short_Break_2,
      SUM(CASE WHEN sub_status = 'LB' THEN pause_sec END) AS Long_Break
FROM vicidial_agent_log
WHERE event_time >= '2021-04-01' AND
      event_time < '2021-04-17'
GROUP BY user;
```

This will probably eliminate the `NULL` values and speed up the query.   However, if there are still `NULL` values in an entire row, it is because there are rows that don't have one of these statuses.  So, just check for them:

```
SELECT user,
      SUM(CASE WHEN sub_status` = 'TB' THEN pause_sec END) AS Training_Break,
      SUM(CASE WHEN sub_status = 'SB1' THEN pause_sec END) AS Short_Break_1,
      SUM(CASE WHEN sub_status = 'SB2' THEN pause_sec END) AS Short_Break_2,
      SUM(CASE WHEN sub_status = 'LB' THEN pause_sec END) AS Long_Break
FROM vicidial_agent_log
WHERE event_time >= '2021-04-01' AND
      event_time < '2021-04-17' AND
      sub_status IN ('TB', 'SB1', 'SB2', 'LB')
GROUP BY user;
```

SQL is very powerful in letting you filter before or after aggregation.  However, it is usually much better (from a performance perspective) to filter before aggregating.

I also advise you to use identifiers that do not need to be escaped.  And, never use single quotes for anything other than string and date literals.